# Python: adjust coordinates to centre of gravity

Tags: python, coordinates

I have a python script where i import coordinates of triangular elements, and element definitions from two seperate text files.

The coordinate file looks like the following:

```
id,x,y,
  1,  0,   0
  2,  0,   1
  3,  0,   2
  4,  1,   0
  5,  1,   1
  6,  1,   2
  7,  2,   0
  8,  2,   1
  9,  2,   2
```

The element file looks like this:

```
id, n1, n2, n3
 1, 1, 2, 4
 2, 1, 2, 5
 3, 2, 3, 5
 4, 3, 5, 6
 5, 5, 6, 8
 6, 6, 8, 9
 7, 5, 7, 8
 8, 4, 5, 7
```

In the script i define a new element (rectangular) when two edges of triangular elements are on the same place. I first define unique nodes for each triangular element (so elements no longer share the same node) then i define a new element by the four nodes in the corners. 
See image below

[image]

This works just fine, however the new defined elements have a thickness of zero. And i do want to have them a fysical thickness. Therefor i want to adjust the coordinates of the nodes of the triangular elements and move them slightly to the centre of gravity of the element.

How can i find the centre of gravity of the triangular elements, and then change the coordinates of the nodes with a value of 0.001 in horizontal and 0.001 in vertical distance in the direction of the centre of gravity of the element?

The script i currently have is the following:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python


open("D://Documents//SkyDrive//afstuderen//99 EEM - Abaqus 6.11.2//scripting//_COORDINATEN.txt", "r")
import csv
import itertools

with open("_COORDINATEN.txt") as file:
    data = csv.reader(file)
    next(data)
    coords = []
    coords = ([[float(x) for x in line[1:]] for line in data])


open("D://Documents//SkyDrive//afstuderen//99 EEM - Abaqus 6.11.2//scripting//_ELEMENTEN.txt", "r")
import csv
import itertools

with open("_ELEMENTEN.txt") as file:
    data2 = csv.reader(file)
    next(data2)
    elems = []
    elems = ([[int(x)-1 for x in line[1:]] for line in data2])


#Flip the original elements if required
for i,elem in enumerate(elems):
    ecoords = [coords[e] for e in elem]

    a = [x2-x1 for x1,x2 in zip(ecoords[0],ecoords[1])]
    b = [x2-x1 for x1,x2 in zip(ecoords[1],ecoords[2])]

    n = a[0]*b[1]-a[1]*b[0]

    if n < 0:
        elems[i] = [ elem[0], elem[2], elem[1] ]

#bewerking elementen
newcoords = []
newelems  = []
for elem in elems:
    ecoords = [coords[e] for e in elem]
    newelem = range( len(newcoords), len(newcoords)+len(ecoords) )

    newcoords += ecoords
    newelems.append( newelem )

cohelems = []
for e,elem in enumerate(elems):
  for edge in [[0,1],[1,2],[2,0]]:

    eedge = [elem[i] for i in edge]

    for e2,elem2 in enumerate(elems[e+1:]):

      e2 += e+1

      for edge2 in [[0,1],[1,2],[2,0]]:

        eedge2 = [elem2[i] for i in edge2]

        if all([i in eedge2 for i in eedge]):

          newedge  = [newelems[e][i] for i in edge ]
          newedge += [newelems[e2][i] for i in edge2]

          cohelems.append( newedge[-1::-1] )
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_triangle_and_tetrahedron

Comment: Thank yo ufor the reply, i know how to find the centre of gravity of a triangle. However i don't know how to program this in python, especially how to change the coordinates of triangular elements in the direction of the centre of gravity

Answer (score 1):

I'll not try to make this correspond exactly to your variable names. Instead, I'll give a general example for how to do the contraction you wanted. You should be able to apply it to your own thing. I'm using one of the formulas on the page that Michael Mauderer linked.

The problem is just vector algebra. If you're not planning on using a vector class for the points in general, it'd at least help to define some vector operations:

```
def add_vectors(*points):
  new_x = 0.0
  new_y = 0.0
  for point in points:
    new_x += point[0]
    new_y += point[1]
  return [new_x, new_y]

def subtract_vectors(a, b):
  new_x = a[0] - b[0]
  new_y = a[1] - b[1]
  return [new_x, new_y]


def mul_by_scalar(vector, scalar):
  new_x = vector[0] * scalar
  new_y = vector[1] * scalar
  return [new_x, new_y]
```

With these, the rest becomes somewhat easier:

```
triangle = [[0,0], [1,0], [1,1]]

# finding the center of mass:
#   CM = (1/3) * (a + b + c)
# CM:       position vector to the center of mass
# a, b, c:  position vectors to the corners

CM = mul_by_scalar(add_vectors(*triangle), 1.0/3)

# For every point of the triangle, find a vector that points towards its CM.
# Scale the vectors to 10% (in this instance).

point_to_CM_vectors = []
for point in triangle:
  point_to_CM_vectors.append(subtract_vectors(CM, point))

# Make a new triangle, contracted by 10%.

new_triangle = []
for point, motion in zip(triangle, point_to_CM_vectors):
  new_triangle.append(add_vectors(point, mul_by_scalar(motion, 0.10)))
```

You can fairly easily see how you could inline the functionality of `add_vectors`, `subtract_vectors` and `mul_by_scalar` to do the operations "by hand", but you'll be repeating yourself constantly and the code will be confusing.